# Android - How do i launch a new class and its activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two activity as below in same project. 
How do i launch the MainActivity from ServicesDemo? I have used the Intent but it does not launch MainActivity.

Mainfest i have only one:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".ServicesDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

When the project launch it start this one:

```
public class ServicesDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
      case R.id.buttonpicture:
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

ServiceDemo needs to launch this also:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
}
```

***EDIT:***

Main fest: multiple activity listed

```
<activity 
    android:name=".ServicesDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">        
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />           
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />     
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Called activity which is needed:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: "I have used the Intent but it does not launch MainActivity" -- there is nothing obviously wrong with that code other than using `getBaseContext()` instead of `this`. Make sure that `MainActivity` is listed as an `<activity>` in  your manifest.

Comment: How about replacing `getBaseContext()` with `ServiceDemo.class`? does that work?

Comment: Please make also sure that your code really matches your case condition and that you reach the startActivity-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the activity you want to launch into the Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Then you can launch it with an intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
startActivity(new Intent("your.package.MainActivity"));
```

Comment: NOTE: its multiple activity i need to launch 1st (service demo) at the same time 2nd ( my activity)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

then you must declare your activity in the manifest

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
```